# How to check the time of a function repeated several times

Tags: r, benchmarking

Suppose i have

```
myFun = function(){

}
```

I know that

```
system.time(myFun)
```

will tell me the time used to run the function. The question is I want to know how much would it take to repeat the calling the function 1000 times, what should I do?

Comment: There are benchmarking packages: `rbenchmark`, `microbenchmark`. There may be others, but I guess there's no Task View for it: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/

Comment: Thank you! The replication argument in benchmark function allows me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### To repeat myFun 1000 times:

```
library(microbenchmark)
myFun <- function() {Sys.time()}
microbenchmark(myFun(), times = 1000)

Unit: microseconds
       expr   min     lq median     uq    max neval
    myFun() 9.893 11.035 11.416 12.176 60.119  1000
```

Comment: Confusing example, but +1 for improving the tags.